# Where are "folder view" desktop settings files located on Kubuntu 18.04?

Tags: kubuntu, icons, kde, desktop-environments, plasma

Every time I reboot, some of my desktop icons disappear from screen 1 and appear on screen 2.

If I try to move them back, KDE shows the normal copy/paste context menu. But if I set screen 2 to **folder view** then back to **desktop** mode, all icons move back to screen 1 automatically.

I think there must be some config file for each screen, set to **folder view** mode, but I can't find where it is.

(I'm using Kubuntu 18.04 with KDE Plasma 5.12.5)